# Ubuntu 20.04 Killer AX500s DBS drivers support

Tags: networking, wireless, kernel, dell, xps

After reading available pages with keywords similar to those included in topic I decided to ask a question since I really don't know what to do.

Few days ago I bought new DELL XPS 15 9500 (i9 version) with network adapter **Killer AX500s DBS**. Wifi and bluetooth isn't visible at all on Ubuntu 20.04[.1] and default kernel 5.4.x. I tried to install the drivers, changed kernels (even to 5.9) but no luck - in last case bluetooth icon appeared but wasn't working properly (even turning it on was failing, if managed to turn it on - couldn't connect to my mouse). I found out that mentioned network adapter is currently not supported:

- certification notes (XPS 13 wth the same module) https://certification.ubuntu.com/hardware/201910-27450
- tracking and additional articles https://www.raxcrucible.com/posts/dell_xps15_9500/

My question is:
Does anyone know if it will be supported soon or ever (I have to decide if I should return new computer - time is limited here)? If no - where should I ask for it? I'm really confused about it and don't know if it's worth to wait.

I found out there is some driver - https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware Does someone tried to install it manually (how? It's last thing I didn't try) and did it work?

output from `lspci`

```
6c:00.0 Network controller [0280] Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
Subsystem Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:a501]
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: 6c:00.0 Network controller [0280] Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
Subsystem Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:a501]

Comment: That github is not a driver, but firmware. It seems the device isn't supported yet.

Comment: Does your 5.9 kernel have the driver ath11k? `sudo updatedb` followed by: `locate ath11k` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: sudo: updatedb: command not found

Comment: Try `sudo apt install mlocate` to install `locate` and `updatedb`.

Answer (score 8):

I just found out there is support for AX500s DBS in the "linux-firmware" package ver 1.187.7, which is currently in ubuntu proposed:
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/1.187.7

I can confirm I'm now running Ubuntu 20.04.1 on XPS 13 9310 (late 2020), connected via the AX500s DBS Wifi.

To get the wifi card recognised, I had to:

```
# sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04-edge # installs kernel version 5.10.0-1008-oem
# sudo apt install linux-firmware=1.187.7 # from ubuntu proposed, which I temporarily enabled
```

Comment: It's working and it's stable? and suspend resume works as well with the wifi?

Comment: On a Dell XPS 17 (9700) with Ubuntu 20.04.2 and just running the first command (`sudo apt install linux-oem-20.04-edge`) fixed the wifi issue.  It also fixed the sound issue!  This brings the kernel up to 5.10.0-1008-oem

Comment: Confirmed working on Dell XPS 15 9500 after installing `linux-oem-20.04-edge` kernel

Comment: The above comment working for me in Dell XPS 17 (9700). But as @tomodachi mentioned the Wi-Fi is not working after suspend the reopen the laptop. I need to restart the laptop every time to get the Wi-Fi working. Anyone knows a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

The issue related to Killer ax500 was resolved by updating the kernel to the version 5.10.3. I am using ubuntu 20.04 and the wifi and Bluetooth are working perfectly.
All the best

Answer (score 1):

I have wifi functional on my XPS 15 9500 i9 (side note: I am running 20.10 not 20.04, so results may very).

I was first looking into this article that claimed to solve the issue: https://medium.com/@tomas.heiskanen/dell-xps-15-9500-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04-d5f1c218e78a, however I found it odd that the linked LKML page said this was added in kernel v5.10-rc2 while v5.10.4 is out.

So first, I updated my kernel to 5.10.4: [https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.4/](https://kernel.ubuntu.com/%7Ekernel-ppa/mainline/v5.10.4/)

Then, as referenced on LKML https://lkml.org/lkml/2020/9/14/964, I cloned https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware and copied the firmware files to the appropriate directory:

```
sudo mkdir -p /lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/
sudo cp QCA6390/hw2.0/WLAN.HST.1.0.1-01740-QCAHSTSWPLZ_V2_TO_X86-1/*.bin /lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/
sudo cp QCA6390/hw2.0/WLAN.HST.1.0.1-01740-QCAHSTSWPLZ_V2_TO_X86-1/bdwlan.e04 /lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/board.bin
```

After that I restarted my computer and had the ability to connect to wifi networks.

Comment: Thanks Nick. I've tried doing what you detailed but, the pathnames used in the cp commands dont exist in the github repository you link to - presumably due to an update. What files dif you actually copy? Did you need to run any other commands / configure any options after copying the files? Thanks

Comment: I am also trying to figure out the commit version or the actual files that were copied. The paths don't exist. My best guess is the .bin and the bdwlan.e04 were all moved to this directory: `https://github.com/kvalo/ath11k-firmware/tree/master/QCA6390/hw2.0/msm/1.0.1.c1.2/WLAN.HST.1.0.1.c1.2-00014-QCAHSTSWPL_SILICONZ-1`

Comment: To follow up, using commit `659f221` from that ath11k-firmware repo, you can copy the `QCA6390/hw2.0/board-2.bin` and `QCA6390/hw2.0/1.0.1/WLAN.HST.1.0.1-01740-QCAHSTSWPLZ_V2_TO_X86-1/(amss.bin|m3.bin)` files into your `/lib/firmware/ath11k/QCA6390/hw2.0/` directory (you may need to create this directory first). then it should work after restarting if you're using a kernel later than 5.10.3 (may exist earlier as well - have not tested).

Answer (score 1):

I'm following this issue for more than 7 months now since I got my Dell XPS 9500, with a Killer Wifi 6 AX500-DBS card. I was able to use it by upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04.2 running on Linux kernel 5.11.

Answer (score 1):

New XPS 15 with fresh 21.04 install two weeks ago 05/05/2021.

I'm having issues, twice in the past 2 weeks, on my new XPS 15 9500 and 21.04 with wifi working fine initially then not available. `lspci` shows the card.

After trying numerous troubleshooting options found online in desperation I usb boot back to 20.10. wifi isn't available there either.

Reboot to installed 21.04 and mysteriously wifi is back on.

```
$ uname -a
Linux XPS-15-9500 5.11.0-17-generic #18-Ubuntu SMP Thu May 6 20:10:11 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I have no idea if booting into trial 20.10 fixed it or if it is incidental???

```
pathp@XPS-15-9500:~$ sudo lshw -C network
[sudo] password for pathp: 
  *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA6390 Wireless Network Adapter [AX500-DBS (2x2)]
       vendor: Qualcomm
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:6c:00.0
       logical name: wlp108s0
       version: 01
       serial: 9c:b6:d0:3f:10:89
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath11k_pci driverversion=5.11.0-17-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.16 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:170 memory:b4200000-b42fffff
```

Answer (score 1):

I received a new XPS 13 9310 and Ubuntu 20.04 did not work, however Ubuntu 21.10 works out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issues with the same laptop (XPS 15 9500 I9 version).
I have noticed that the support for Killer wifi ax500 will be available with the release of the new kernel 5.9.

The stable version will be released on 11th of October or next week.

Comment: I see it's already released! Let me know if it works for You.

Comment: @luk07 where can I find this driver in the kernel? https://github.com/torvalds/linux/tree/master/drivers/net/wireless does not have qualcomm

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't manage to make it work and returned my laptop. Driver was named at11k. I see someone installed it with success - https://medium.com/@tomas.heiskanen/dell-xps-15-9500-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04-d5f1c218e78a

Answer (score 0):

sorry for the delay but during the last days i tried to resolve the issue.
Finally, i found a guide that resolve the AX500 issue for me, following step by step this guide https://medium.com/@tomas.heiskanen/dell-xps-15-9500-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04-d5f1c218e78a

Some suggestions

- don't install the new kernel 5.9 before. During the procedure you will install also the kernel 5.9rc5 (yes, is a release candidate and maybe will have some issues, i will test it during the next days);
- before to start with the guide, install pahole (minimum version required is 1.16). You can find the link here for version 1.17.1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/d/dwarves-dfsg/dwarves_1.17-1_amd64.deb
- when you will finish to set the configuartion file in the guide, save it as .config.

I  hope that this will work also for you.

Answer (score 0):

I bought a standard (not developer version) XPS 13 9310. The AX500 wifi chip was not recognized by the normal 20.04 or 20.10 Ubuntu installations.

I tried a nightly version of the upcoming 21.04. The installer does not have the driver for the Wifi, but after installation the AX500 is recognized and working fine. I was connected to Ethernet during the installation, I dont know if the driver is in the standard installer or was pulled in as an update during installation. When installing I would recomend being connected to the network somehow just to make sure the AX500 driver is available afterwards.

Here is the link to the Ubuntu 21.04 daily builds:

https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with the machine on ubuntu 20.10. I upgraded to 21.04 and now the WiFi is working

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm Dell XPS 15 9500 i9 Ubuntu 20.04 after updating the kernel to version 14 Wi-Fi is back working properly