# Ubuntu 20.04.01 - Kernel v5.10-rc2

Tags: wireless, kernel, 20.04, dell

I received my new Dell XPS 15 9500 - Core i9, but it came with a Wi-Fi board that is not yet supported by Ubuntu (`20.04.01`): Killer AX500-DBS.

I followed some instructions [here](https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg205031.html) on how to install the latest kernel `5.10-rc2` and fix the issue, which actually work and enable the Wi-Fi. But there is a big problem: I can't boot twice in a row using the `5.10 kernel`, otherwise it won't boot. It shows 3-4 initialization messages and the journal checks, but then the screen goes black and only a blinking cursor appears. If I boot before using the `5.4` (original ubuntu) kernel, and then boot to the `5.10`, sometimes it works.

1. Any ideas on how to fix this?
2. Any ideas about when ubuntu will use the `v5.10` of the kernel?

Some links I have read so far:

- https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg205031.html
- https://www.spinics.net/lists/linux-wireless/msg203111.html
- https://medium.com/@tomas.heiskanen/dell-xps-15-9500-wifi-on-ubuntu-20-04-d5f1c218e78a
- [Ubuntu 20.04 Killer AX500s DBS drivers support](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1280328/ubuntu-20-04-killer-ax500s-dbs-drivers-support)

Comment: You are using the leading edge kernel and adding a brand new, relatively un-tested driver, so expect problems. If it were me, I would try an unmodified kernel 5.10-rc2 to determine if the reboot issue is a problem with 5.10-rc2 or a problem introduced with the driver. (by the way, I can reboot kernel 5.10-rc2 just fine).

Comment: At the moment, this is all upstream of Ubuntu, and isn't supported here. You should closely monitor the [linux wireless e-mail list](https://marc.info/?l=linux-wireless&r=1&b=202011&w=2), perhaps even join the list for this. Anyway, in that list I see a few potentially related patches that should be in kernel 5.10-rc3. I also observe some potentially related patches queued into a "next" type branch, which I do not know when it gets applied to the master.