# How can I get my qualcom wifi adapater working on Ubuntu 20.10?

Tags: wireless

Laptop is DELL XPS 17, this does not appear to be the Atheros controller frequently mentioned on this site.

I do have a RJ45 dongle that works, so I can download what is necessary.

Bleeding edge hardware and linux... :(

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Qualcomm
   vendor: Qualcomm
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d2100000-d21fffff
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:a501]
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

tx$ uname -r

```
5.8.0-25-generic
```

atx$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```

jjs@atx$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

jjs@atx$ uname -r
5.8.0-50-generic

It just stalls. Just sitting here.  Htop shows no CPU activity.

jjs@atx$ sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i
Finding latest version available on kernel.ubuntu.com
Latest version is: v5.11.15, continue? (y/N)

```
Will download 6 files from kernel.ubuntu.com:
Downloading amd64/linux-headers-5.11.15-051115 generic_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_amd64.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/linux-headers-5.11.15-051115_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_all.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.11.15-051115-generic_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_amd64.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/linux-modules-5.11.15-051115-generic_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_amd64.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/CHECKSUMS: 100%   
Downloading amd64/CHECKSUMS.gpg: 100%   
Importing kernel-ppa gpg key ok
Signature of checksum file has been successfully verified
Checksums of deb files have been successfully verified with sha256sum
Installing 4 packages
```

Now it is just stalled, it sits there, htop shows no CPU for process.

Laptop is DELL XPS 17, this does not appear to be the Atheros controller frequently mentioned on this site.

I do have a RJ45 dongle that works, so I can download what is necessary.

Bleeding edge hardware and linux... :(

```
sudo lshw -C network
*-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Qualcomm
   vendor: Qualcomm
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d2100000-d21fffff
```

lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
04:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:a501]
05:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL7540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge [Titan Ridge 4C 2018] [8086:15ea] (rev 06)
    Kernel driver in use: pcieport
```

tx$ uname -r

```
5.8.0-25-generic
```

atx$ lsb_release -a

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.10
Release:        20.10
Codename:       groovy
```

jjs@atx$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

jjs@atx$ uname -r
5.8.0-50-generic

per https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-10-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

jjs@atx$ sudo ubuntu-mainline-kernel.sh -i
Finding latest version available on kernel.ubuntu.com
Latest version is: v5.11.15, continue? (y/N)

```
Will download 6 files from kernel.ubuntu.com:
Downloading amd64/linux-headers-5.11.15-051115 generic_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_amd64.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/linux-headers-5.11.15-051115_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_all.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/linux-image-unsigned-5.11.15-051115-generic_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_amd64.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/linux-modules-5.11.15-051115-generic_5.11.15-051115.202104161034_amd64.deb: 100%   
Downloading amd64/CHECKSUMS: 100%   
Downloading amd64/CHECKSUMS.gpg: 100%   
Importing kernel-ppa gpg key ok
Signature of checksum file has been successfully verified
Checksums of deb files have been successfully verified with sha256sum
Installing 4 packages
```

Now it is just stalled, it sits there, htop shows no CPU for process.

Ran again and it completed.

Rebooted and got:

```
error: /vmlinuz-5.11.15-051115-generic has invalid signature.
error: you need to load the kernel first.
```

Disabled Secure boot now

atx$ uname -r
5.11.15-051115-generic

atx$ sudo lshw -C

```
   description: Network controller
   product: Qualcomm
   vendor: Qualcomm
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   version: 01
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list
   configuration: driver=ath11k_pci latency=0
   resources: irq:196 memory:d2100000-d21fffff
```

atx$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3

```
04:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Device [17cb:1101] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:a501]
    Kernel driver in use: ath11k_pci
    Kernel modules: ath11k_pci
```

atx$ lsb_release -A

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:     Ubuntu
Description:        Ubuntu 20.10
Release:    20.10
Codename:   groovy
```

But when searching for networks it doesn't show my router, which my phone sees and uses.

In addition to kernel version 5.11,you also need required firmware. Please do:

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.197_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb

reboot

SUCCESS!!!

Comment: We need more detailed information. Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: detail requested added to question.

Comment: Let's also see: `uname -r` and `lsb_release -a`

Comment: Added, thanks for the quick responses.  Try that with Fedora! :)

Comment: You need kernel 5.10. edit: see for instance https://askubuntu.com/a/1304400/15811

Comment: Thanks, I just did an apt upgrade but I am on kernel 5.8.

Suggestions?

Comment: I will try this, which should bring me up to 5.11

https://www.how2shout.com/linux/how-to-install-linux-kernel-5-10-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts/

Comment: Is your computer still hung?

Comment: No, it boots to kernel 5.11 but still doesn't see the router, but it sees the wifi controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to kernel version 5.11,you also need required firmware. Please do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.197_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb
```

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: WOOHOO, I know have a usable $4k notebook.  Now to get the sound working, I will make that a separate question.

Thank you very much.

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour I'm very glad it's working!