# USB modem not working in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: usb-modem

I have this modem which works fine in windows 10 but not detected at all in ubuntu.
/home/johnk/Documents/1.jpg
It has the following information at the back.

Model no : BD-6818
HSDPA WIRELESS DATA CARD USB STICK
BD TECHNOLOGY (HK) CO.LIMITED

It is not detected by lsusb and I get this message from dmesg

```
[ 3706.384952] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 37 using xhci_hcd
[ 3712.520202] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3713.500576] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3713.500653] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 3714.549241] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3715.517706] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3715.517805] usb usb2-port1: unable to enumerate USB device
[ 3716.514848] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3717.508167] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
[ 3717.508252] usb usb2-port1: attempt power cycle
[ 3718.584187] usb usb2-port1: Cannot enable. Maybe the USB cable is bad?
```

I was once detected by usb-devices as
...

```
Manufacturer=Qualcomm,incoparated
product=qualcomm cdma technologies msm
```

...

but never again.

I think I have tried most of stuff from google and nothing was helpful. Am I missing something they dont just work in ubuntu.

Comment: A shot in the dark: Some of those devices need a firmware package. If it works when you boot Windows first and then Linux, that may point to that general direction: In that case, Windows loads firmware into the device, and rebooting without really powering down the machine tends to keep it there.

Comment: Does this help, https://askubuntu.com/a/1332512/29073 ?

Comment: I have only ubuntu in my pc. I tested the dongle in another pc. I'll add windows 10 and try that.