# Wifi driver ubuntu for honor 16

Tags: drivers, wireless, internet

I installed ubuntu 20.04 on honor magicbook 16 and now I can't connect to internet. Tell me where to find the driver for wifi?

lspci -knn | grep Net -A3 output:

Network controller [0280]: Qualcomm Device [17cb:1103] (rev 01)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of  `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3` terminal command in order to identify the hardware (brand/model of the computer is often irrelevant because the same product can have different chips). And you may need a newer kernel than the one running in a 2 years old release. BTW, Ubuntu 22.04 is due to release today.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331410/how-can-i-get-my-qualcom-wifi-adapater-working-on-ubuntu-20-10