# Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 Module stopped working properly after attempted driver update

Tags: drivers, atheros

I am running ubuntu 22.04.3 on Honor Magicbook 15.
I have been experiencing random crashes latelty and was trying to look into them. I decided to start with checking my drivers.
I wanted to check if my drivers were up up-to-date. Stumbled upon this post: [How to download all required Ubuntu drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/543325/how-to-download-all-required-ubuntu-drivers). Following top answer's instructions I ran:

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers install   
sudo reboot
```

Afterwards, it looked like my laptop crashed or something went wrong. After a reboot I cannot connect to any Wi-Fi network. They are simple not displayed in "Networks" tab in bottom right corner.

Here are some things I have checked and believe could be useful:
**iwconfig** output:

```
lo        no wireless extensions.

docker0   no wireless extensions.
```

**rfkill list all**:

```
0: hci0: Bluetooth
        Soft blocked: yes
        Hard blocked: no
```

**lswh** (only copied entries I found weird):

```
*-network UNCLAIMED
                description: Network controller
                product: Atheros QCNFA765
                vendor: Qualcomm
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
                version: 01
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d0000000-d01fffff
*-multimedia:1 UNCLAIMED
                description: Multimedia controller
                product: Raven/Raven2/FireFlight/Renoir Audio Processor
                vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD]
                physical id: 0.5
                bus info: pci@0000:03:00.5
                version: 01
                width: 32 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: cap_list
                configuration: latency=0
                resources: memory:d0580000-d05bffff
```

**lspci | grep -i net**

```
01:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCNFA765 (rev 01)
```

**lsmod | grep ath**

```
ath11k_pci             32768  0
ath11k                860160  1 ath11k_pci
qmi_helpers            32768  1 ath11k
mac80211             1720320  1 ath11k
cfg80211             1318912  2 ath11k,mac80211
mhi                   106496  1 ath11k_pci
```

**sudo dmesg | grep ath11k**

```
[   10.674942] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: BAR 0: assigned [mem 0xd0000000-0xd01fffff 64bit]
[   10.674969] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   10.675742] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: MSI vectors: 32
[   10.675751] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: wcn6855 hw2.1
[   39.952577] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to power up mhi: -110
[   39.952584] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to start mhi: -110
[   39.952591] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to power up :-110
[   39.968380] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to create soc core: -110
[   39.968390] ath11k_pci 0000:01:00.0: failed to init core: -110
[   40.165512] ath11k_pci: probe of 0000:01:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Also, I can provide any additional information regarding this issue.

Answer (score 0):

After hours of hitting the wall, I have finally figured it out.

Important note! I was completely unaware of what I was doing and why. I was simply replicating solutions I found online from people having issues close enough to mine.

My laptop doesn't have port for Ethernet connection and of course I don't own an adapter for that. So the first thing was to somehow get internet access on my computer.

1. It turns out that phones can share cellular data through USB alone.
   Here is simple [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pN4x2IO14s4) for Android phones that I used to do exactly that.
2. I tried updating everything I could:

   - `sudo apt update`
   - `sudo apt upgrade`
   - `sudo apt install linux-firmware`
3. I tried `sudo modprobe ath11k` where ath11k stands for the name of my driver.
4. I restarted my laptop.
5. I checked if the error was still present with `dmesg | grep ath11k` and indeed it was. At this point I realized that apparently my system could recognize my network module and it even saw that I have suitable driver for it installed, but for some reason, wireless connection interface of my network module still wouldn't appear on any command like `ifconfig`, `iwconfig` or `rfkill list all`.
6. The thing that I think made the difference (outlined in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1331410/how-can-i-get-my-qualcom-wifi-adapater-working-on-ubuntu-20-10)), run:

   - `wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.197_all.deb`
   - `sudo dpkg -i linux-firmware*.deb` - this one actually gave me an error, I don't know what's up with that.
7. I rebooted once again, losing all hope that was left.
8. Upon reboot I get greeted by working and already connected Wi-Fi. What a pleasant surprise! I think this whole experience once again taught me that with computers, and Linux specifically, the most important thing is not to give up. The solution is somewhere out there. You just have to keep trying.

Again I do not understand or know what most of these things mean and if they actually did anything for me or not, but I know for sure that after doing exactly this, it all worked out for me.